# Postgres multicolumn vs combined single column indexes

Tags: postgresql

The answer is always "run it and see how it works on your dataset" of course, but looking for general guidelines here. I have three queries:

```
... WHERE A = '...' AND P = '...' AND Q = '...'
... WHERE B = '...' AND P = '...' AND Q = '...'
... WHERE C = '...' AND P = '...' AND Q = '...'
```

The first query featuring `A` will be more common. Any general recommendations on whether to use 5 separate single column indexes, or whether to use 3 combined `(A, P, Q)`, `(B, P, Q)`, `(C, P, Q)` ?

Comment: Check the [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Answer (score 2):

If the `P = '...' AND Q = '...'` is highly selective, I would just put one index on that pair of columns and leave it at that.  If it is only moderately selective and if I needed individual indexes on A, B, and C anyway for other queries, then I'd probably tack P and Q onto the end of each of those indexes, unless the P and Q columns are wide and so would bloat the size of the indexes.

I wouldn't use 5 separate single column indexes for this, unless I needed each one for some other purpose anyway.  They would have to be combined with a BitmapAnd, which is much less efficient than using a multi-common index with equality conditions.